# Random error on external Oracle database connection with Kubernetes

Tags: node.js, oracle, docker, kubernetes

After month of research, we are here, hoping for someone to have a insight about these issue:
On a GKE cluster, our pods (node.JS) are having trouble connecting to our external oracle business database.

To be more precise, ~70% of our connection tentative are ending in error:

> ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist

The 30% left are working well, and doesn't reset or end prematurely. Once it's connected, it's all good from here.

**Our stack:**

- Our flux are handed by containers based on a node:12.15.0-slim image, at which we add LIBAIO1 and a instant oracle client (v12.2). We use oracleDB v5.0.0 as node module
- We use cron job pod handling our node container, in a clusterIP service on a GKE cluster (1.16.15-gke.4300).
- Our external oracle database in on a private network (which our cluster have access), in a Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi version, behind a load balancer

I can give more detail if needed.

**What we have already tried:**

- We have tried to pass directly on the database, cutting off the load balancer: no effect
- We had cron job pod doing ping each min on the database server for a day: no error, although flux pod somehow encounter the ORA-12545 error
- We redo all our code, connecting differently to the database and making update for our node module oracledb (v4 to v5): no effect
- We tried to monitore the load up over the oracle database and take action spreading our flux over all night instead of a 1 hour window: no effect
- We had our own kubernetes cluster before GKE, directly in our private network, causing the exactly same error.
- We had a audit by some expert on kubernetes, without them finding the issue or seeing a critical issue over our cluster/k8s configuration

**What works:**

- All our pods, some requesting into mySql database, micro service, web front, are all working fine.
- All our business tool (dozen of, including Talend and some custom software) are using the oracle database without issue.
- Our own flux handling node container are working fine with the oracle database as long they are into a docker env, and not a kube one.

**To resume: We have a mysterious issue when trying to connect to an oracle database from a kubernetes env, where pods are randomly unable to reach the database**

We are looking for any hint we can have

Comment: The db resource is not found from within your pods. Can this be a routing issue? Are you sure packet are going out to external db instead of being routed inside the k8s cluster? Since it works for some and not for others, make sure you identify the subnet and ip for the different pods and spin up a test-pod-full-of-tooling where you can go over connecttvity to the db.  client 12.2 and server 10g has never been supported. But it might work 30% of the time :-)

Comment: try also upgrading the database driver https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb